# installed windows 2003 in VMware cant get internet to work

Tags: internet, vmware

I have installed Windows 2003 server in VMWare and cannot seem to get the internet to work.  It says it is connected to the internet in the box in the icon bar and when I run ipconfig it returns with an ip subnet and default gateway however when I open the browser go to Google run a search in Google then click on a website it will not connect.  It is configured using NAT but I have tried in  bridgemode as well.  If anyone has a solution to this problem I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You're using a 18 year old operating system. It shipped with [Internet explorer 7][1] it seems. IE7 at that time did obviously not support more modern TLS versions and ciphers. This is likely why a connection to google fails. I didn't find any tables for Win2003, but for XP [it only supported SSL 2 and 3, not TLS 1.0](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=IE&version=6&platform=XP&key=100) when released. In short: you have to either set up a proxy that strips away modern TLS, or you must install some newer browser through other means. Running such a OS is wildly insecure, and the

Comment: I don't see a security question here, i.e. off-topic.

Comment: @vidarlo: as I read it OP _does_ get results from google, but can't connect to the site(s) linked in those results. During roughly 2008-2012 I used primarily XPSP3 with IE7 and IE8 and those did support TLS1.0 (ssllabs agrees for 8 and doesn't list 7) which google as of now does accept (at least for search, I didn't try mail etc). I remember issues around 2012 when CAs started issuing certs with SHA256 instead of SHA1, which on XP SP3 (only) could handle, but Server2003 never got an SP3 and needed a manually-downloaded hotfix, and I have no clue if that's still available.

Comment: ... Of course any site that accepts card payments is prohibited by PCI for several years now to use TLS1.0 and discouraged from using 1.1. There are probably such requirements in many other places by now.